# How to create a place holder in Date picker wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am tying to set a place holder in the Datepicker . But i cant set .

```
<toolkit:DatePicker  ValueStringFormat="{}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"  Value="" Header="Dob"   x:Name="dateofBirthRegPick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="191,545,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251" BorderBrush="#FF3691E2"  Background="White" Foreground="Black" Template="{StaticResource DatePickerControl}"/>
```

when the

```
ValueStringFormat="{}Dob :{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"
```

then i am getting the concatenated output like below

```
Dob :10-12-2018.
```

Please help me how can i set a place holder in Date picker ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, please be more specific.

Comment: I need a placeholder in Date picker. How is it possible